# react-native: expo app: Something went wrong Could not load expo error suddenly

Tags: react-native, expo

I used expo app with **LAN** connection in ubuntu by my phone, and it worked well until yesterday.

But today, I tried **yarn start** as yesterday in same environment, but I have error like below photo. The **LAN** and **Local** doesn't work like below, and The **Tunnel** does work, but when I tried request to my server I made in my same computer with django, the server have no request from my phone.

[image]

I saw same issues and solutions in Internet, but there is nothing work for me. Do you have any solutions or tips for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using LAN connection, then -

1. Go to the network property option and make is public (thus your laptop or mobile phone will be discoverable from other devices). It is necessary, to your laptop and phone discover or say find each other.
2. Make sure that they are connected via the same network.
   If, none of the above works, then, try updating the expo cli and project too. Sometime, the update of expo cli package causes the same problem too. If there are major changes.
   Hope, it will work for you.
   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are more people who have troubles like me.

To tell you the conclusion, it is working well at now with doing nothing.

Since it didn't work, I tried to run with my phone regularly, but it didn't work.
But, Despite doing nothing, it suddenly started working.

I don't know why it wasn't working, but if you suddenly have troubles like me, Just do the other things and try it later.

Answer (score 0):

**Change your Network and Internet setting:-**

Please follow these steps:-

Network and Internet setting--->>Status-->>Change connection properties-->Checked public option

Answer (score 0):

well...here is what worked for me.
Open android studio > more actions > avd manager > actions, wipe the phone data. And then start your emulator over again.