# Expo build not working with react-native and android studio

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo

### It was working previously

I was tasked with context switching over to a higher priority project. A month later the project is on hold so I came back to this expo react-native project, and it failed to run. I saw there was a version update error. So I updated to the latest in the package.json. Then I saw the app failed to load on android studio.

### The Problem

And so I tried creating a new project(after uninstall/re-install everything), and same issue...

##### Ran with powershell, created new project using nodejs, and ran expo using nodejs.

[image]

##### Android Studio(Virtual Device with Pixel 3 and Oreo 8.1 build, sdk Android 8.1 and Android API 34)

[image]

Log error: `Uncaught Error: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://192.168.50.19:8081/...`

### My guess on why this is happening

I've noticed expo has made several fundamental recent changes to deprecate some of their tools, for example:

- cli has been deprecated and must now use npx to run doctor, install the app, and run the app.
- many recent versions of sdk support has been deprecated due to not having enough of a user base.

I'm making an educated guess in saying I think this issue is recent with their latest version, and I don't know if there are any solutions out there yet to fix this. Has anyone run into this problem?

### Other solutions I've tried

So I've already checked all the solutions I could find(including many from other sources), and none of them work for me. Most are 3 years old to a few months old. Most generally say "wait it out" till they fix the next version. This isn't optimal for our team. Here are some of the solutions I have tried from stackoverflow:

[Can't load expo app: Something went wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002144/cant-load-expo-app-something-went-wrong)

[react-native: expo app: Something went wrong Could not load expo error suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996879/react-native-expo-app-something-went-wrong-could-not-load-expo-error-suddenly)

[Expo app will not run on Android Emulator (Error) Something went wrong. Could not load exp://127.0.0.1:19000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72745949/expo-app-will-not-run-on-android-emulator-error-something-went-wrong-could-no)

Comment: 2024 having similar problem on Ubuntu. Running doctor command for sdk gives `Version supported: Not Found` and in another project gives me `Version supported: .b33.0.0` Main problem is I can't build the apk file.

Comment: @user31782 So oddly enough I found out my work blocked port 8080, which is the default port expo uses to run the project. When I executed the command `npx expo run:android --port 8082`, this solved the issue.

Comment: I actually had png image issue. Somehow I had a jpeg rename to png file and on build gradle was throwing error. I can now build successfully, but I still get a lot of warnings: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/26998